# TimeUtils.millis() Java

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Пожалуйста объясните как получить секунду в Java.

Я вообще не понимаю что такое , TimeUtils.nanoTime(). Он выдает какие то космические цифры. Я не пониманию на что делить эти милисы. Пожалуйста объясните как получить секунду в Java. Иными слова как сделать секундомер. 1 2 3

Comment: Не нужно задавать один и то же вопрос несколько раз.

Comment: Зачем приследовать меня, если не можешь помочь?

Comment: Вот есть игра Мортал Комбат. Один раунд длиться минуту. Как это реализовать? Неужели это настолько сложная задача

Answer (score 0):

Для конвертации можете использовать `TimeUnit`. Пример: `TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(elapsedTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);`
 
- где `elapsedTime` ваше значение в наносекундах.
Также для реализации секундомера можете использовать `Handler`. Пример:

```
private static final int MIL_IN_SECOND = 1000;
...
new Handler().postDelayed (() -> {
   //your code here
}, MIL_IN_SECOND);
```